# How to JOIN Four tables, with muliple constraints

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have to write a SQL statement to show a sum for similar types, I also need add another exclusion constraint from another table.

This is using Microsoft Access 2010.
The problem reads:  Write an SQL statement to show the sum of HoursWorked for each Type of OWNER but exclude services of employees who have an ExperienceLevel of Junior and exclude any Type with less than three members.

```
 SELECT OWNER.Type, SUM(HoursWorked) AS Total_Work_Hours
FROM OWNER AS O, PROPERTY AS P, SERVICE AS S, EMPLOYEE AS E
WHERE O.OwnerID = P.OwnerID
AND P.Property= S.PropertyID
AND S.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
AND O.Type>3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  You also need a proper `GROUP BY` and should be qualifying all column references:

```
SELECT o.Type, SUM(HoursWorked) AS Total_Work_Hours
FROM ((OWNER AS O INNER JOIN
       PROPERTY AS P
       ON O.OwnerID = P.OwnerID
      ) INNER JOIN
      SERVICE AS S
      ON P.Property = S.PropertyID
     ) INNER JOIN
     EMPLOYEE AS E
     ON S.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE O.Type > 3 AND
      E.ExperienceLevel <> 'Junior'
GROUP BY o.Type
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: :-) old-style joins are still as much "standard" as they have always been.

Comment: Thank you, I will! I am learning still and I am still trying to better understand how to join tables, there seems to be a lot of ways to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
SELECT O.[Type], SUM(e.HoursWorked) AS Total_Work_Hours,count(e.employeeid) as Total_Members
FROM OWNER AS O, PROPERTY AS P, SERVICE AS S, EMPLOYEE AS E
WHERE O.OwnerID = P.OwnerID
AND P.Property= S.PropertyID
AND S.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
AND e.ExperienceLevel NOT IN ('Junior')
Group by o.[Type]
Having count(e.employeeid)>=3;
```

Comment: For some reason I still get the same error, to enter a parameter for OWNER.Type

Comment: Then you must have been writing incorrect column name for `owner.type`. verify it's name in database

Comment: "Enter Parameter Value ?" Owner Type. The name of the table is Owner, and the column name is Type.

Comment: you may check now

Comment: If possible kindly edit your question and provide all tables and their columns names.

Comment: `Type` is a reserved name in Microsoft Access. You shouldn't use that as object or field names. Because that can cause such behaviour, try to replace `Type` by `[Type]` in your query to clear that it is a field name.

Comment: I have tried [Type] and ['Type'], also tried parenthesis brackets

Comment: Share the tables structure please. So that I may assist you precisely

Comment: For the Owner Table. Column Names are OwnerID, OwnerName, Email, Type. Data Types are Autonumber, Short Text, Short Text, Short Text. Respectively